# Paypal not calculating shipping after discount code (big cartel)

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, bigcartel

When checking out from big cartel, it directs me to paypal however when I add the discount code in bigcartel in the paypal summary the shipping is determined from the base price not after the discounted price.

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 1):

it sounds like this could be an issue with your Big Cartel or PayPal shipping settings. This site is a Q&A site for programmers, so you'll have the best luck with emailing Big Cartel support. http://bigcartel.com/contact